# Filtering spam / scraped / auto generated sites from Google alerts

Tags: spam-prevention, google-alerts

I use Google alerts to monitor our company name online, my alerts search query is:

```
"Company Name" OR "company.com" -site:pinterest.com
```

Recently we have seen a ton of spam sites crawling, article spinning other sites and then publishing them on pages covered in advertising. The pages are practically illegible to humans and just a random collection of industry terms, display ads (usually served by Google.. the irony) and keywords which sometimes include our company name, as the site they scraped must have had an article about us.

The only thing I've thought of so far is to block them by individual domain, in the same way I have blocked Pinterest in the query above, failing that I was thinking perhaps by IP range. But these both are manual fixes and would have to be constantly updated.

Is there a stronger way I can block these sites from showing up in my Google alerts feed. I've found Google alerts to be a really great tool in the past, but with 99% of the alerts being spam its a pain to read through the alert emails.